# Doing a running count on non-partitioned data in Google bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got some data that looks like the below

```
Date  | Priority
----------------
01/01 | Low
02/01 | Low
03/01 | Low
04/01 | Med
05/01 | Med
06/01 | Low
07/01 | High
08/01 | High
09/01 | Med
...
```

I want to add a column in that displays how many days it's been in the current priority, so it would look like this:

```
Date  | Priority | Days in state
--------------------------------
01/01 | Low      | 3
02/01 | Low      | 2
03/01 | Low      | 1
04/01 | Med      | 2
05/01 | Med      | 1
06/01 | Low      | 1
07/01 | High     | 2
08/01 | High     | 1
09/01 | Med      | 1
...
```

I'm struggling to do that because there's no way I can partition the data as it stands. Partitioning on Priority takes into account every occurrence of that priority in history rather than just the current "window".

I've used `IF(LAG(priority) OVER(ORDER BY date) = priority,1,0)` to flag when there's a change but I can't figure out where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  For your purposes, the simplest method is probably to subtract a sequence and use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by status, grp order by date date desc) as days_to_next_state
from (select t.*,
             date_add(date, interval - seqnum day) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by status, order by date) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT date, Priority, 
  1 + DATE_DIFF(MAX(date) OVER(PARTITION BY grp), date, DAY) Days_in_state
FROM (
  SELECT date, Priority, 
    COUNTIF(start_new_Priority) OVER(ORDER BY date)grp
  FROM (
    SELECT date, Priority, 
      IFNULL(Priority != LAG(Priority) OVER(ORDER BY date), TRUE) start_new_Priority
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question result is

```
Row date        Priority    Days_in_state    
1   2019-01-01  Low         3    
2   2019-01-02  Low         2    
3   2019-01-03  Low         1    
4   2019-01-04  Med         2    
5   2019-01-05  Med         1    
6   2019-01-06  Low         1    
7   2019-01-07  High        2    
8   2019-01-08  High        1    
9   2019-01-09  Med         1
```